# Does Intel Smart Response provide any statistics on the cache usage?

Tags: ssd, cache, intel-core-i7

I've set up my Z68-based Core i7 PC with a 60GB SSD dedicated as a Smart Response cache drive. Is there any way I can get any statistics out of it? It would be nice to have some information on how much cache space is actually being used, maybe how much of it was actually accessed recently, and how many reads in general are coming from the SSD rather than from the mechanical disk.

These statistics might help to quickly provide some evidence for or against the use of Smart Response, without my having to reinstall Windows on the SSD (etc.) to find out.

The Windows ReadyBoost feature has some performance counters you can access via the Windows 7 perfmon tool, for example, which is the kind of thing I'm hoping is somehow available. Smart Response provides no perfmon counters, though, and the Intel Rapid Storage Utility tells you pretty much nothing except that Smart Response is switched on.

Comment: Smart Response makes SSD unavailable for other uses. Maximum usage is 64GB though

Comment: SmartResponce won't be faster than a pure SSD implementation, and a pure HDD implementation would be slower than both of them.  What are you looking to prove? Why can't you just spend the time to reinstall and test it?  Have you checked with Intel's development resources?

Comment: Thanks for the note! Do you have a link for Smart Response-related dev resources? Regarding what I'm looking to prove - nothing specific, I'd just like some numbers to go on. I could spend the time to reinstall and test, but it will take 1 day just to do the reinstall part. It would be more cost-effective to get any numbers that are available, and make an educated guess.

Comment: What I would be looking to prove is that the SRT algorithm is in fact working well for my particular workload. Collecting real numbers around cache hit rates etc. makes for far better decision making than "I installed it and it seems to take 3 seconds now instead of 5", or "it feels faster now" guesstimates.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I never found anything, nor have I ever heard of any tools that will tell you anything. Would be nice to have some numbers that reflect use over a long period, though, as it's impractical to time every single last operation. (My best guess is that SRT didn't really take off, and Intel aren't supporting it much, betting that reduced SSD prices and increased reliability will make it irrelevant sooner rather than later. Fingers crossed for that.)